# How to load and compile Gedit+GTK+ sources for debugger

Tags: debugging

I would like to learn how to make a text editor using GTK+. I think the best way to do this is to watch what is happening in the code when one runs Gedit. I have been told that one has to compile the sources of Gedit and GTK+ for -g option. But as I am a very beginner of open source world, I would like to know

1. How can I load the sources of GTK+ and Gedit to my computer?
2. How to compile them to one package which can run on debugger?
3. How to run the Gedit and debugger so that I can see what is going on when one runs the program?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I haven't done debugging earlier so I thought that DDD or Nemiver would be the easiest to learn but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu, simply do:

```
cd ~/Desktop  # or wherever you want it
apt-get source gedit  # does not need sudo
```

Check the **README** / **INSTALL** files - they should give you plenty information about compiling, just adapt the instructions to your needs. For a simple compile it's just:

```
  ./configure
  make
```

---

The GEdit main development page is at: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/
You can get the upstream source code using `git clone git://git.gnome.org/gedit`

Comment: OK. I compiled the program as 

sudo ./configure CFLAGS=-g
sudo make
cd gedit/

But now ddd ./gedit shows the code but how can I run it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ./configure --enable-debug so it contains debug information in the first place (usually, C executable don't which is why they are so small).
So to correct the above from what you have now:
make clean
./configure --enable-debug
make

In DDD, F5 is step, F6 is next, F8 is finish and you can set breakpoints.